# html table edit the rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html table and i want to edit the contents of the table based on a button click.

My HTML code:

```
 <form name="myform">
<table id="tblFollow" >
    {% for key, value in result.iteritems() %}
<tr>
    <td > {{ key }}</td>
    <td> <div id="editableText" > {{ value }} </div></td>

</tr>
    {%  endfor %}
</tbody>
   </table>
<h>  {{  passvalue }} </h> <br>
<input type="button" onclick="changeContent()" value="Change content">
 </form>
```

and my javascript is

```
    function changeContent(){
        var newstate = !editableText.isContentEditable
        editableText.contentEditable = newstate
        editableText.className = (newstate)
    }
```

but the problem is when i click on the button only the first rown on the table is showing editable. otherthan that all the rows are immutable. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm thinking your javascript is possibly looking for an id, but it finds the first one and stops. If you have more than one object, it's better practice to use classes. You probably need to search for all divs with the same class and iterate over each of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `class` instead of `id`. [Id's are meant to be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Common_CSS_Questions#What_is_the_difference_between_id_and_class.3F).

```
<div class="editableText" > {{ value }} </div>
```

Then in your javascript, you need to loop over the selected elements:

```
function changeContent(){
  var editables = document.getElementsByClassName('editableText');
  for (var i = 0; i < editables.length; i++) {
    var newstate = !editables[i].isContentEditable;
    editables[i].contentEditable = newstate;
  }
}
```